# Android Application showing blank screen

Tags: android

I tried to run my app. But instead of showing the MainActivity(which is the launcher activity, it is showing just blank screen).

public class FireApp extends Application {

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

}
```

}

This is the separate class I created for my firebase app to fire up on every activity. And yes I have included it in the manifest file.

Comment: Activity code is a bit missing

Comment: MainActivity  ?................

Comment: the launcher Activity's `onCreate()`